# Unable to place an Image view within the content of a Modal

Tags: swift, swiftui, simplemodal

I am having a problem with understanding why my modal object will not allow an Image view, but would allow a Text view. I also have a Grid object displaying images that is not causing any issues. Overall, I do not see why an Image View is causing conflict.

```
if showPhotoModal {
                Modal(content: AnyView(
                    
                    VStack{
                        HStack {
                            Image(uiImage: self.imageToUpload)                         }.padding(.horizontal)
                        Grid(0..<self.photos.allPhotos.count, id: \.self) { index in
                            self.image(in: index)
                        }.gridStyle(StaggeredGridStyle(.vertical, tracks: 3, spacing: 4))
                    }
                    
                ), header: AnyView(Text("Pick your photo")), isPresented: $showPhotoModal)
            }
```

`showPhotoModal` is controlled by a button press and will ideally present a VStack with a HStack with two elements and a grid. With the code above I get an error at the main stack (ZStack) stating that `Static member 'top' cannot be used on instance of type 'Alignment'`. My best guess is the VStack is not correctly configured for modal object. Modal view is pretty simple, if you need me to post that I can.

Modal Code:

```
public var body: some View {
    
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        ZStack {
            
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                HStack {
                    self.header
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        withAnimation {
                            self.isPresented = false
                        }
                    }) {
                        ZStack {
                            Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill))
                                .font(.system(size: 31))
                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .bold))
                        }
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                
                Divider()
            
                self.content
            }
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .top)
            .background(Color.white)
            .cornerRadius(15)
            .offset(y: self.stateValue == 2 ? self.translation - 100 : (self.stateValue == 1 ? geometry.size.height*0.4 + self.translation : geometry.size.height*0.7 + self.translation))
            .animation(self.animation)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value.translation.height
                }.onEnded { value in
                    print(value)
                    if self.stateValue == 1 && value.translation.height < -90 {
                        self.stateValue = 2
                    } else if self.stateValue == 1 && value.translation.height > 90 {
                        self.stateValue = 0
                        self.isPresented = false
                    } else if self.stateValue == 0 && value.translation.height < -90 {
                        self.stateValue = 1
                    } else if self.stateValue == 0 && value.translation.height > 90 {
                        self.stateValue = 0
                        self.isPresented = false
                    } else if self.stateValue == 2 && value.translation.height > 90 && value.translation.height < 350 {
                        self.stateValue = 1
                    } else if self.stateValue == 2 && value.translation.height >= 250 {
                        self.stateValue = 0
                        self.isPresented = false
                    }
            })
        }
    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
            withAnimation {
                self.backgroundOpacity = 0.08
            }
            self.animation = .interactiveSpring()
        }
    }
    
}
```

There are variables and an init function that set the header, content, and isPresent properties.

Comment: Can you post your Modal code? It might the the issue

Comment: Haha thank you for editing the question! What I found funny is you didn’t include the part I wanted you to include. The header of Modal. Let me guess is it something like this? ‘struct Modal<Content: View> : View {‘

Comment: Lol. The header is public struct Modal: View {. Does '<Content: View>' matter for this? I do have an init function that handles the properties

Comment: Theoretically, it shouldn't matter but its best practice.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to replicate the bug you are witnessing. If possible either create a code that we can copy and paste fully to reproduce bug or try to explain more of the issue.

Here is your code where I tried to guess couple things based on your comments that is working 100% fine for me

```
struct StackOverflow33: View {
    var body: some View {
        Modal(content: AnyView(
            
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }.padding(.horizontal)
                //                    Grid(0..<self.photos.allPhotos.count, id: \.self) { index in
                //                        self.image(in: index)
                //                    }.gridStyle(StaggeredGridStyle(.vertical, tracks: 3, spacing: 4))
            }
            
        ), header: AnyView(Text("Pick your photo")), isPresented: .constant(true))
        
    }
}

struct StackOverflow33_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackOverflow33()
    }
}

struct Modal: View {
    var content: AnyView
    var header: AnyView
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    
    init(content: AnyView, header: AnyView, isPresented: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.header = header
        self.content = content
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                
                
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    HStack {
                        self.header
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.isPresented = false
                            }
                        }) {
                            ZStack {
                                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill))
                                    .font(.system(size: 31))
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .bold))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                    self.content
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .top)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                //                .offset(y: self.stateValue == 2 ? self.translation - 100 : (self.stateValue == 1 ? geometry.size.height*0.4 + self.translation : geometry.size.height*0.7 + self.translation))
                //                .animation(self.animation)
                //                .gesture(
                //                    DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                //                        state = value.translation.height
                //                    }.onEnded { value in
                //                        print(value)
                //                        if self.stateValue == 1 && value.translation.height < -90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 2
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 1 && value.translation.height > 90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 0
                //                            self.isPresented = false
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 0 && value.translation.height < -90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 1
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 0 && value.translation.height > 90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 0
                //                            self.isPresented = false
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 2 && value.translation.height > 90 && value.translation.height < 350 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 1
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 2 && value.translation.height >= 250 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 0
                //                            self.isPresented = false
                //                        }
                //                })
            }
        }
        //        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        //        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        //        .onAppear {
        //            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
        //                withAnimation {
        //                    self.backgroundOpacity = 0.08
        //                }
        //                self.animation = .interactiveSpring()
        //            }
        //        }
        
    }
}
```

Note: I have commented out irrelevant code parts that in theory shouldn't effect end results. If however, you are witnessing something else I highly recommend you post a code that we can easily reproduce and avoid the guessing work.

Additionally, I wouldn't really create an `init` for my header or content. this way I can avoid using `AnyView` and keep my code clean.

here is how I would do it.

```
struct StackOverflow33: View {
    var body: some View {
        Modal(isPresented: .constant(true), header: {
            Text("Pick your photo")
        }) {
            VStack{
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                }.padding(.horizontal)
                //                    Grid(0..<self.photos.allPhotos.count, id: \.self) { index in
                //                        self.image(in: index)
                //                    }.gridStyle(StaggeredGridStyle(.vertical, tracks: 3, spacing: 4))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StackOverflow33_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackOverflow33()
    }
}

struct Modal<Content, Header>: View where Content : View, Header : View{
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    var header: () -> Header
    var content: () -> Content
    
    
    public var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                
                
                VStack(spacing: 0) {
                    HStack {
                        self.header()
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            withAnimation {
                                self.isPresented = false
                            }
                        }) {
                            ZStack {
                                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.secondarySystemFill))
                                    .font(.system(size: 31))
                                Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                    .foregroundColor(Color.secondary)
                                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .bold))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                    self.content()
                }
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height, alignment: .top)
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                //                .offset(y: self.stateValue == 2 ? self.translation - 100 : (self.stateValue == 1 ? geometry.size.height*0.4 + self.translation : geometry.size.height*0.7 + self.translation))
                //                .animation(self.animation)
                //                .gesture(
                //                    DragGesture().updating(self.$translation) { value, state, _ in
                //                        state = value.translation.height
                //                    }.onEnded { value in
                //                        print(value)
                //                        if self.stateValue == 1 && value.translation.height < -90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 2
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 1 && value.translation.height > 90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 0
                //                            self.isPresented = false
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 0 && value.translation.height < -90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 1
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 0 && value.translation.height > 90 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 0
                //                            self.isPresented = false
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 2 && value.translation.height > 90 && value.translation.height < 350 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 1
                //                        } else if self.stateValue == 2 && value.translation.height >= 250 {
                //                            self.stateValue = 0
                //                            self.isPresented = false
                //                        }
                //                })
            }
        }
        //        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        //        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
        //        .onAppear {
        //            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
        //                withAnimation {
        //                    self.backgroundOpacity = 0.08
        //                }
        //                self.animation = .interactiveSpring()
        //            }
        //        }
        
    }
}
```

From the above code you can see where I am initializing my views and there is no need for an `init` any more. Also pay attention to the order of my variables as it's very important.

If you really need an `init` function then this is how it should be

```
    init(isPresented: Binding<Bool>, header: @escaping () -> Header, content : @escaping () -> Content) {
        self._isPresented = isPresented
        self.header = header
        self.content = content
    }
```

Comment: I figured it out. I was using the incorrect uiImage value and was causing issues. The error was throwing me off completely. I restarted Xcode and noticed I need to use the variable within imageToUpload. I did implement the changes you mentioned to clean up my code. Thanks! On to the next, which looks like observable objects #complete_noob

Comment: Great! sometimes the compiler is bad at giving errors. If you need help don't be hesitate to drop a comment linking other questions! Goodluck!

Comment: Hi @Muhand, could you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63706885/while-using-coredata-to-cache-postitems-i-am-not-seeing-any-post-on-view-after