# While using CoreData to cache postItems, I am not seeing any post on view after saving

Tags: swift, core-data, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am not entirely sure how to explain this problem since I am new to CoreData, but the way I implemented this functionality is shown below:

```
...
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: PostItem.getAllPosts()) var postItems:FetchedResults<PostItem>
@ObservedObject var observed = observer()
@ObservedObject var postobserved = Postobserver()
...
init() {
        self.setUpPosts()
    }
...    
func setUpPosts() {
    for i in postobserved.posts{
        let post = PostItem(context: self.managedObjectContext)
        post.type = i.type
        post.user = i.user
        post.image = i.thumb
        post.id = i.id
        post.text = i.text
        post.comment = i.comments
        post.video = i.media
        do{
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        }catch{
           print(error)
        }
    }
}
...
var body : some View{
        ZStack(alignment: .center){
                VStack{
                    if self.postItems.isEmpty {
                        Text("No Posts").fontWeight(.heavy)
                    } else {
                        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false){
                            ForEach(self.postItems) { post in
                                PostCard(showComment: self.$showComment, post: post)
                                .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1)).cornerRadius(50).padding()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

After setting up my dataModel and the class that will reference that dataModel, I am still confused on how CoreData is not saving these posts. I do not get an error. Maybe postObserved is not setup with posts yet which is causing setUpPosts to not save any data to the dataModel. Any help to push me in the right direction would be helpful.

As of right now the iOS simulator just displays "No Posts" which means that postItems is empty.

Comment: Why not rule out some possible errors by creating some PostItem objects in setUpPosts with hard coded values and check if it they are displayed properly.

Comment: I set up some dummy values to see what error I would get and I received: "-[snatched.PostItem setId:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000015ca0d0." This appears in the AppDelegate class. I am not sure what setId is referring to

Comment: I guess it is called when setting the `id` property but what is `snatched`? Set a breakpoint inside setUpPosts and run it in the debugger to see if the crash come from there